# Access server through URL

Tags: networking, ip

I'm attempting to access a server in my network through my browser like so:

```
http://192.168.1.201/
```

But it stops me as it requires a log in.

How can I include my credentials in this URL? I'm using IE in this case.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the webserver is throwing up a login prompt and that this is done through HTTP basic authentication, you can provide the username and password in the URL by `http://user:password@192.168.1.201/`

Do note that the password in this case will be sent in the clear and anyone listening in on your net will be able to intercept it.